# ActionScript set padding bottom (or margin bottom) to something smaller

Tags: actionscript-3, padding

I have a VGroup, and inside of it I am going to have a variable amount of VGroups which have 2 HGroups inside of them.

So something like:

```
VGroup
  VGroup
   HGroup 
   HGroup
  VGroup

  VGroup
   HGroup 
   HGroup
  VGroup

  VGroup
   HGroup 
   HGroup
  VGroup
  .
  .
VGroup
```

Now, I want to have the inner VGroups have somewhat big bottom padding (margin). Then, I want the HGroups to have bottom padding too but smaller. Make sense? Well so I am trying to set the paddingBottom style on the first HGroup inside an inner VGroup, but nothing is changing. This is in ActionScript. Here's what I have:

```
  var innerVGroup:VGroup = new VGroup();

   var hGroup:HGroup = new HGroup();          
   hGroup.setStyle("paddingBottom", "5px") ;
   var number= new Label();
   number.text = clients[j].clientNumber;
   hGroup.addElement(number);


  innerVGroup.addElement(hGroup);


  hGroup = new HGroup();
  var userName:Label = new Label();
  userName.text = clients[j].displayName;
  hGroup.addElement(userName);

  innerVGroup.addElement(hGroup);


  this._view.outterVGroup.addElement(innerVGroup);
```

And that above code is in a for loop which will just keep creating and adding innerVGroups to the outterVGroup.

However, the bottom padding between my innerVGroups and hGroups are the same. I've even tried setting the bottomPadding style to like 1px, -100px, 500px... never changes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the gap on innerVGroup worked.

innerVGroup.gap = 0;

Answer (score 0):

In Flex, for styles that have pixel values we don't use `5px` we just use `5`. So this should work:

```
hGroup.setStyle("paddingBottom", 5);
```

Comment: I did that, but it still didn't change anything. No matter what I give it, it's always the same bottom padding.